# I cannot display the index containing the highest value of integer. but i can display the highest value of integer in the array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, max

I cannot display the index containing the highest value of integer. but i can display the highest value of integer in the array.
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main () {

    int a[10], highest,temp = 0;
    do{

        cout<<"Enter 10 Numbers: ";
        cin>>a[temp];
        temp++;
    }while(temp !=10);

    for(int j = 0; j <10; j++){
        if(a[0]<a[j]){
            highest = j;

        }
    }   

    for(int x = 0; x <10; x++){
        if(a[0]<a[x]){
            a[0] = a[x];
        }
    }
    cout<<"The highest number is "<<a[0] <<" at index "<<highest<<endl; 
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(a[0]<a[j]){
   
   highest = j;
  }` What are you checking for seriously?

Comment: i assume j is my array index. as it has the same value with my array size.

Answer (score 1):

For starters do not use magic numbers as for example the number 10 in your program. Use named constants instead.

Also declare variables in the minimum scope where they are used.

This loop

```
for(int j = 0; j <10; j++){
if(a[0]<a[j]){
highest = j;

}
```

does not make sense because it searches the last element in the array that is greater than the element `a[0]`. It is not the same as searching the index of the greatest element.

Also as the variable `highest` is not initialized then in general the program has undefined behavior.

Instead of two loops you can use one loop that finds the index of the greatest element.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how it can be done.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int a[N];

    std::cout << "Enter " << N << " umbers: ";

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) std::cin >> a[i];

    size_t max = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( a[max] < a[i] ) max = i;
    }

    std::cout << "The highest number is " << a[max] 
              << " at index " << max << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter 10 umbers: 7 2 3 0 9 1 8 6 4 5
The highest number is 9 at index 4
```

Take into account that there is standard algorithm `std::max_element` declared in the header `<algorithm>` that finds the maximum element in a sequence and returns iterator/pointer to it.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int a[N];

    std::cout << "Enter " << N << " umbers: ";

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) std::cin >> a[i];

    int *max_value = std::max_element( a, a + N );

    std::cout << "The highest number is " << *max_value 
              << " at index " << std::distance( a, max_value ) << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look as shown above

```
Enter 10 umbers: 7 2 3 0 9 1 8 6 4 5
The highest number is 9 at index 4
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are storing the highest value in a[0] you need to swap it with the new greater values if found after each iteration a bit of some code in your program should look like:

```
 for(int j = 0; j <10; j++){
    if(a[0]<a[j]){
        int tmp = a[0];
        a[0] = a[j];
        a[j] = tmp;
        highest = j;
    }
}
```

- A simple, readable example looks like:

  ```
  int a[10], highest = -1, highestIndex = -1;

  for(int i(0); i < 10; i++){
      cout<<"a[" << i << "]: ";
      cin >> a[i];
  }


  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      if(a[i] > highest){
          highest = a[i];
          highestIndex = i;
      }
  }   

  cout << "The highest number is " << highest << " at index " << highestIndex << endl;
  ```
- Please don't ask for a `while-do loop` you can handle it.

Comment: tnx a lot mate. :) i want to have that level of skill in no time :)

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your code detects the highest index of an element that is larger than the first element, not of the element that has the highest value of all:

```
for(int j = 0; j <10; j++){
  if(a[0]<a[j]){
    highest = j;
  }
}
```

This is because you always compare to `a[0]` (which does not change), rather than to the highest value reached so far.
The second loop for finding the highest value itself, in contrast, works because you change `a[0]` to the "local" maximum found so far.

```
for(int x = 0; x <10; x++){
  if(a[0]<a[x]){
    a[0] = a[x];  // remembers the maximum found so far for further comparisons
  }
}
```

You could easily combine both as follows. Note (as a minor thing) that it is sufficient to start from `1`:

```
int indexOfMax = 0;
for(int x = 1; x <10; x++){
  if(a[0]<a[x]){
    a[0] = a[x];  // remembers the maximum found so far for further comparisons
    indexOfMax = x;  // stores the index of this element.
  }
}
```